# Is it possible for Travis CI to be configured to build in multiple OS X versions?

Tags: macos, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I need to ensure my code runs on OSX 10.9, 10.10 & 10.11. Travis has a flag for building in the OS X environment (default being 10.9) - in `.travis.yml`:

`os:
  - osx`

and flags for [individual OSX/Xcode combinations](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment#OS-X-Version), but it seems only one of these at a time can be specified -e.g:

`osx_image: xcode7`

Is it possible to specify in `.travis.yml` combinations of OS X (& Xcode) & if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can test different versions of Xcode and its accompanying version of [OSX](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/#OS-X-Version) by customizing the build matrix in your .travis.yml:

```
language: python
matrix
   include:
      #test OSX 10.9
       - os: osx
         osx_image: beta-xcode6.2
      #test OSX 10.10
       - os: osx
         osx_image: xcode6.4
      #test OSX 10.11
      - os: osx
        osx_image: xcode7.3
```

More information about testing on multiple OSs can be found [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/).